# Get a nested element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the ul element which is nested in some spans just after the select element.
How can I do this with jQuery ?

```
<select id="my-select" class="my-select">
  <option value="1">One value</option>
  ...
</select>

<span class="first-span">
  <span class="second-span">
    <span class="third-span">
      <ul class="my-list"> 
        <li class="">First li</li>
        ...
      </ul>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative, if you have unable to use class, use `next()` and `find()`.

Example:

```js
let result = $('#my-select').next('span').find('ul li').text();
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="my-select" class="my-select">
  <option value="1">One value</option>

</select>

<span class="first-span">
  <span class="second-span">
    <span class="third-span">
      <ul class="my-list"> 
        <li class="">First li</li>

      </ul>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select it in many ways, for example by class:

```js
$('.my-list')
```

or if you want to be more precise for example:

```js
$('span.third-span > ul.my-list')
```

**Working example:**

```js
console.log($('span.third-span > ul.my-list').children().length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="my-select" class="my-select">
  <option value="1">One value</option>
  ...
</select>

<span class="first-span">
  <span class="second-span">
    <span class="third-span">
      <ul class="my-list"> 
        <li class="">First li</li>
        ...
      </ul>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```